# Kubernetes: how to assign pods to all nodes with sepcific label

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to run certain job on every single node in specific node groups.
Can kubernetes do the same thing like Swarm global mode?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 4):

To complete @David Maze answer:

A **DaemonSet** is used to create a Pod on each Node. More information [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/).

Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd-elasticsearch
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: fluentd-elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: fluentd-elasticsearch
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: fluentd-elasticsearch
        image: k8s.gcr.io/fluentd-elasticsearch:1.20
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

If you want to schedule Pods not on every Node, you can use **Taints and Tolerations** concept. Taints and tolerations work together to ensure that pods are not scheduled onto inappropriate nodes. For more information, look through the [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/).

For example:

You can add a Taint to a Node:

```
kubectl taint nodes <Node_name> key=value:NoSchedule
```

After that, Pods will have no opportunity to schedule on that Node, even from a DaemonSet.
You can add toleration to a Pod (or to a DaemonSet in your case) to allow it schedule on the Node with the toleration:

```
tolerations:
- key: "key"
  operator: "Equal"
  value: "value"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/).